# Prove a lower bound on an expectation.

Tags: combinatorics, normed-spaces, expected-value

Say $f:[n]\times[n]\rightarrow\{-1,1\}$. Here $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$.

Prove that
$\mathbb{E}_{x,x',y,y'}f(x,y)f(x,y')f(x',y)f(x',y')\geq\frac1n$.

This is the expectation over all possible values of $x,x',y,y'$.
Also $x,x',y,y'$ are iid and uniform.

This expectation is actually a norm as we proved in class, but I don't know how to use that.

I was trying to use the fact that this expectation equals $\mathbb{E}_{x,x'}\left(\left(\mathbb{E}_yf(x,y)f(x',y)\right)^2\right)$.

I was thinking of using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality somehow. I'm unsure how to continue.

Comment: are you missing some conditions?  e.g. at minimum the four variables must be independent, right?  are they even i.i.d.?

Comment: The four variables are randomly sampled from [n]. All values in [n] have an equal chance of being picked. They are iid.

Comment: Oh they are i.i.d. and _uniform_!  Please edit your question to mention that.